# Convert List to Data frame for analysis

Tags: r, list, dataframe

[image]

I am trying to move my list data into a data frame. I want the data frame to look like the image attached. I have tried several methods and I cannot get it. Any help would be appreciated here is my code

```
    symbols <- c('DPZ','SPY','AMD','AAPL','TSLA','MSFT','V', 'WMT', 'SQ','EA','ATVI','AMZN','ROKU', 'PYPL','KO','AXP','CCL','DFS')
getSymbols(symbols, src="yahoo", from='2014-01-01', to='2018-12-31', auto.asign = TRUE)
symb_list <- mget(ls(pattern = paste(symbols, collapse = "|")))

returns_list <- lapply(symb_list, monthlyReturn, subset = NULL, type = 'log', leading = TRUE)

data.frame(t(sapply(returns_list,c)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rbind` with `do.call`

```
do.call(cbind, returns_list)
```

---

Or with `bind_cols`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_cols(returns_list, .id = 'symbol_name')
```

If the `list` elements are `matrix`es, first convert to `data.frame`

```
library(purrr)
map_dfc(returns_list, as.data.frame, .id = 'symbol_name')
```

---

Or may be, we can do a `join`

```
reduce(returns_list, full_join)
```

---

Or with `Reduce` and `merge`

```
out <-  Reduce(merge, returns_list)
colnames(out) <- paste0(names(returns_list), colnames(out))
head(out)
#           AAPLmonthly.returns AMDmonthly.returns.1 DPZmonthly.returns.2 SPYmonthly.returns.3
#2014-01-31         -0.10438527          -0.11551289          0.013689063         -0.032032798
#2014-02-28          0.04995000           0.07847162          0.113035241          0.044510326
#2014-03-31          0.01975642           0.07775936         -0.026791284          0.003857503
#2014-04-30          0.09476128           0.01975373         -0.034228700          0.006927466
#2014-05-30          0.07019541          -0.02225061         -0.026290421          0.022941215
#2014-06-30          0.02728622           0.04640637          0.008794876          0.015654326
```

Comment: I would like it to look like the included picture. I know how to make it look that way from an excel file, however, I am having no success using strictly R. Also, I am getting an error with the second function

Comment: @fighttender you want to `cbind` instead of `rbind`

Comment: The cbind works, however, I have lost the names for each stock.Would I need to reassign names?

Comment: @fighttender i changed the `bind_cols` and `map_dfc`

Comment: @fighttender if it is an xts object, you could also do a join.  can you cechk the updates

Comment: I used colnames(my.portfolio) <- c('DPZ','SPY','AMD','AAPL','TSLA','MSFT','V', 'WMT', 'SQ','EA','ATVI','AMZN','ROKU', 'PYPL','KO','AXP','CCL','DFS')
my.portfolio to apply names to the columns, however, I am getting NA on some of the stock prices for some months

Comment: The updates did not work. Also, I am trying to do this solely in R

Comment: @figthtender with `Reduce`, I get the output and it is working.  DO you need the column names to change?

Comment: @fighttender if i do `out <-  Reduce(merge, returns_list);
colnames(out) <- paste0(names(returns_list), colnames(out))`

Comment: With your code it is removing/ not accounting for the names of the stocks. I need to know which stock is which. The Reduce(merge) code is also working but does not have col names. I am unsure about the NA I am getting on some stocks like AMZN and KO. These stocks existed during the entire duration that I specified.

Comment: @fighttender I changed the column name with `paste0(` if you have checked my previoius comment

Comment: It is very close Thank you. I will continue to make some tweaks figure out why I am getting NA for some of the stocks when there was no NA in the list format.

Comment: @fighttender the only reason would be that it is doing a merge and it iis merging based on the date as it is merge.xts and if some symbols don't have corresponding dates, it would result in NA